# Distribute $13$ identical balls in $6$ cells. Find the number of distributions such that at least $10$ balls will be in the first 3 cells together

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

*Let $13$ identical balls be distributed in $6$ cells. Find the number of distributions in which there are at least $10$ balls in the first $3$ cells together.*

***My attempt:***

First I'll divide into cases: $A_{0},A_{1},A_{2},A_{3}$
$\sum_{i=0}^{3}A_{i}=$ all distributions possible.
This is a question where the order matters and reparations
is allowed. Given $n$ balls and $k$ cells, there are: $\binom{n+k-1}{n}$
ways to distribute $n$ balls to $k$ cells.

$A_{0}$ - there are $13$ balls in the first $3$ cells, and $0$ balls in the $3$ other cells thus $k_{1}=3,n_{1}=13\Longrightarrow$$\binom{n+k-1}{n}=\binom{15}{13}=105$ ways to distribute $13$ balls between $3$ cells. The distribution of balls in the first $3$ cells is disjointed to the distribution of balls in the other $3$ cells, therefore we'd apply the multiplication principle:
number of ways to distribute $0$ balls in $3$ cells: 
$\binom{2}{0}=1\Longrightarrow A_{0}=\binom{15}{13}=105$

$A_{1}$ - there are $12$ balls in the first $3$ cells,
and $1$ ball in the $3$ other cells:

$k_{1}=3,n_{1}=12,k_{2}=3,n_{2}=1 \Longrightarrow\binom{n_{1}+k_{1}-1}{n_{1}}\cdot\binom{n_{2}+k_{2}-1}{n_{2}}=\binom{15}{12}\cdot\binom{3}{1}=455\cdot3=1365$

$A_{2}$- there are $11$ balls in the first $3$ cells,
and $2$ ball in the $3$ other cells:

$k_{1}=3,n_{1}=11,k_{2}=3,n_{2}=2$}$\Longrightarrow\binom{n_{1}+k_{1}-1}{n_{1}}\cdot\binom{n_{2}+k_{2}-1}{n_{2}}=\binom{15}{11}\cdot\binom{4}{2}=1365\cdot6=8190$}

$A_{3}$- there are $10$ balls in the first $3$ cells,
and $3$ ball in the $3$ other cells:

$k_{1}=3,n_{1}=11,k_{2}=3,n_{2}=3 \Longrightarrow\binom{n_{1}+k_{1}-1}{n_{1}}\cdot\binom{n_{2}+k_{2}-1}{n_{2}}=\binom{15}{10}\cdot\binom{5}{3}=3003\cdot10=30030$}

$\sum_{i=0}^{3}A_{i}=105+1365+8190+30030=39690$

> I'm not sure that my answer is correct, it seems to me that my result is to big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close, but have made a small mistake in calculating ${n_1 + k_1 - 1 \choose n_1}$: the top argument does not always equal $15$. You should find:

$$A_0 = {15 \choose 2} {2 \choose 2} = 105$$
$$A_1 = {14 \choose 2} {3 \choose 2} = 273$$
$$A_2 = {13 \choose 2} {4 \choose 2} = 468$$
$$A_3 = {12 \choose 2} {5 \choose 2} = 660$$

$$A_0 + A_1 + A_2 + A_3 = 105 + 273 + 468 + 660 = 1506$$

Comment: why $\binom{14}{2}$?  the number of balls in the first 3 cells is $12$, and the number of balls is the other 3 cells is $1$. 13 balls in total

Comment: @Jneven For $A_1$, there are twelve balls and two bars, so fourteen elements in total. Have a look at your formula, and plug in the values for $n_1$ and $k_1$ in the four different cases!

Comment: what is bars? do you mean cells? there are 3 cells

Comment: @Jneven For $A_1$, we have $n_1 = 12, k_1 = 3$, so $n_1 + k_1 - 1 = 14$.

Comment: I'm talking about the n. according to your answer: $\binom{n-k+1}{n}=\binom{14}{2}$, but  is the number of balls, not the number of cells. we have 12 balls to distribute between 3 cells

Comment: What we're dealing with here, is what we call a [stars-and-bars problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), in which $k - 1$ bars divide $n$ stars among $k$ cells. The reasoning here is that if there are $n$ items to divide among $k$ cells, we simply need to choose $k - 1$ locations for the bars among $n + k - 1$ locations. Then, the remaining $n$ spaces contain the stars. Applying this approach to $A_0$, we need to choose two locations for the bars among fifteen locations; while there are only fourteen locations for $A_1$. Is this explanation clear?

Comment: Why don't you divide $ A_i $ by $ 2! $? we don't care if we first distribute to cells 1,2,3 and then to 4,5,6 or vice versa ( order doesn't matter ).

Comment: @hazelnut_116 We indeed do not care about order. For this reason, I have not specified a unique set of balls to divide among the first three cells. Rather, I simply calculated the number of ways in which we can assign thirteen balls to the first three cells (corresponding to $A_0$), twelve balls to the first three cells and one to the last three cells (corresponding to $A_1$), etcetera. The mentioned combinations only apply to solving the stars-and-problem, not to dividing the balls among the first and the last three cells. Also note that all balls are unique, according to the original post.